# Upgrade to Websphere Network Deployment from Base Version

Tags: websphere, upgrade

I have a websphere application server installation, the versioninfo.sh command show this

---

### IBM WebSphere Application Server Product Installation Status Report

Report at date and time August 2, 2012 2:53:08 PM GMT+07:00

### Installation

Product Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
Version Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs
Backup Directory         /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/nif/backup
TMP Directory            /tmp

### Product List

BASE                     installed

### Installed Product

Name                     IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version                  7.0.0.17
ID                       BASE
Build Level              cf171115.15
Build Date               4/16/11
Architecture             AMD (64 bit)

---

### End Installation Status Report

Can I upgrade this installation directly to Websphere Network Deployment edition?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that. This involves installing and creeating Deployment manager's profile and federating this server to that Dmgr's Cell.